# Twitter4j - GET users/lookup and method lookupUsers()

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j to retrieve my followers/friends and I got a problem with the method lookupUsers().

Basically the users/lookup endpoint (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup) returns a parameter called ***following*** embedded in the object "User".

I can't find that value in the Entity twitter4j.User and therefore I am not able to understand if a user that has just been converted is following me or not.

Is that bug?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I have found the problem. Basically this class https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/4.0.2/twitter4j-core/src/internal-json/java/twitter4j/UserJSONImpl.java doesn't contain the parameter **following** therefore it's skipped during the deserialization process. I have fixed it, you can find a working version here https://github.com/db80/twitter4j